# How to reverse words in a string and letters in those words unless the word is a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello & it's nice to be with you all.
I was successful in reversing arrays using the built-in functions    `.split('').reverse().join('')` presented in this site, but I need to keep digits in order, not reversed. Is there anything to do or to add to let it exclude the digits from being reversed, or to re-reverse the digits only after reversing the full array?
Here's the array flipping function,

```
function reversey(){
var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
text = text.replace(/\r/gi,'');
text = text.replace(/([^a-z 0-9\n])/gi,' $1 ');
text = text.split('\n').reverse().join('\n');
text = text.split('').reverse().join('');
text = text.replace(/ ([^a-z 0-9\n]) /gi,'$1');
document.getElementById('input').value = text;}
```

The 'input' is the text-field's ID.
I appreciate your help everyone, thanks in advance.

**Example**

*Input:* `Hello World 123.45`

*Desired output:* `123.45 dlroW olleH`

*Current output:* `54.321 dlroW olleH`

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems a little unclear to me, maybe you could add an example - i.e, sample input, what you would want the output to be and what you are getting instead.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the miss.
an input like (Hello World 123.45) will be reversed to (54.321 dlroW olleH). I'd like it to exclude digits from the reversing, like (123.45 dlroW olleH). Thanks for you.

Comment: That's not necessarily trivial, and we're not a free algorithm-writing service. What have you come up with so far?

Comment: Don't mix up retrieving values from the DOM and putting them back with basic string manipulation algorithms. Design a stand-alone function called `ReverseWordsButNotNumbers` or something. Then you can call it from some other function which grabs stuff from the DOM and puts it back.

Comment: Thanks @tora for reshaping my question to the proper way it should be, & pard me it was my first ever online question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"hello 123.45".split(/([^\d\.])/).reverse().join('')
```

Comment: Super-cool, you win. However, I *think* that "hello wo123rld" should yield "dlr321low olleh", but your solution gives "dlr123ow olleh". A bug, not a feature?

Comment: As simple it is as effective it works. Thanks @user2418306 a lot, I've inserted your line after removing the 4th & 7th lines from the function's code above, & it's done it's job very well.

Comment: @torazaburo `"hello w123d w1234 1234d 12r45 123.45".split(/(^[+-]?(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+))\b)|(\s)((?=[+-\.]?\d)[+-]?(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+))\b)|(.)/).reverse().join('')` good enough?

Comment: @user2418306 It might be worth highlighting the little-known feature of `split` you used, which is that "If separator is a regular expression **that contains capturing parentheses**, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array."

Comment: @tora I see it's not a bug, but the in-build function he made is doing what it supposed to do; reversing every char & 'stick' the digits (along with options) on their 'chairs'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [array `map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It allows you to handle each part of a `split`ted string separately before re-`join`ing them to the result string. You can do something like

```
text.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(line) {
    return line.split(/(\d*\.?\d+)/).map(function(wordOrNum, i) {
        if (i%2) // number (with odd index in the alternating list)
            return wordOrNum;
        else // word
            return wordOrNum.split('').reverse().join('');
    }).reverse().join('');
}).join("\n")
```

Or, split each line into tokens of either single characters or whole numbers, whose sequence you then can reverse:

```
    return line.match(/(\d*\.?\d+|.)/g).reverse().join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we define the standard string reversal function.

```
function reverse(str) { return str.split('').reverse().join(''); }
```

Then,

```
function reversey(str) {                        // Reverse a string
    return str                                  // by taking it and      
        .split(/\s+/)                           // splitting it into words
        .reverse()                              // and reversing the word order
        .map(function(word) {                   // and then changing each word
            return /^[0-9\.]+$/.test(word) ?    // if it's a number
                word :                          // into itself
                reverse(word);                  // or otherwise into its reverse
        })
        .join(" ")                              // put Humpty Dumpty back together
    ;
}
```

#### Test

```
> reversey("Hello World 123.45")
  "123.45 dlroW olleH"
```

To use this to transform the DOM element:

```
function reverse_input(id){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.value = reversey(element.value);
}

reverse_input('input')
```

Note: the implementation of `reverse` given above is not necessarily the optimal way to reverse a string in terms of performance. There are likely to be better alternatives if performance is an issue.

Comment: sigh @ code dump. How is this guy supposed to learn how to write his own programs?

Comment: The `It's not really that hard` comment is rude and unnecessary. Nice solution, by the way, but won't get my upvote. Also, reversing a string by creating an array is slow http://jsperf.com/reverse-words-in-string

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Go ahead, ding me a point, I deserve it. It's just the momentary serotonin rush of solving a problem and hoping for some upvotes. As for the generalized pedagogical problem you raise, your guess is as good as mine. I suppose we could start off by discouraging people with low aptitude from going into programming. Or, we could just close "write me some code" type questions; maybe we should. Or, we could write tutorial-type answers, which no-one would read, I've written my fair share. Or, we could comment over and over again, "show us what you've tried". I'm stumped.

Comment: @tora: Gee, god forbid the people who wish to learn programming should have to take on any of the responsibility themselves.

Comment: @JuanMendes sorry, that comment had no deeper meaning, removed now. WRT performance, the intent here was to show the outlines of algorithm, later I will rewrite the string reversal logic in 8086 assembler for maximal performance.

Comment: You get my vote now that the answer is not mean. My comment about performance is just a note, not a knock on your code. Also, for completeness, consider adding `document.getElementById('input').value = reversey(document.getElementById('input').value)` to emphasize the separation of concerns you mentioned in your comment @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's not just a code dump, it has nice comments explaining each line. The OP can learn from this.